# Show Dialog when Input value changes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am working on a Sharepoint application Page to Uplaod a File to a document libary. The Upload can take a bit of time so I want to display the waiting for it Dialog. I check if all requiered fields are filled in my Upload Button Click Method and then i want show the Dialog. I just need a way to call a javascript fucntion within my Code behind. I tried :

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" runat="server" value="" onchange="ManageWaitingDialog()" />
```

and

```
 if (fieldsfilled) 
        {
            hidden.Value = "SHOW";
 }
```

The event does not fire when I change the value of my input.  Any Help is Welcome thanks.

Comment: `if (fieldsfilled) 
{
 hidden.Value = "SHOW";
 ManageWaitingDialog();
}`  you can call the function after updating the value

Comment: It gives me a compile error because  `ManageWaitingDialog()` is javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Event is triggered only when the value is changed from the browser. If you change the value from code, do not expect that the events will be triggered. You can use the below code to fulfill your requirements.

```
if (fieldsfilled) 
        {
            hidden.Value = "SHOW";
            ManageWaitingDialog();
 }
```

Comment: please see my prevoius comment

Comment: @Zion in that case you need to create a JS function which will periodically check if hidden.value="SHOW"? if its true, it will call the other function